# Deleting related records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, myisam

I have two MySQL (MyISAM) tables:

```
Posts: PostID(primary key), post_text, post_date, etc. 

Comments: CommentID(primary key), comment_text, comment_date, etc.
```

I want to delete all the comments in the "Comments" table belonging to a particular post, when the corresponding post record is deleted from the "Posts" table.

I know this can be achieved using cascaded delete with InnoDB (by setting up foreign keys). But how would I do it in MyISAM using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE
    Posts,
    Comments
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Comments ON
    Posts.PostID = Comments.PostID
WHERE Posts.PostID = $post_id;
```

Assuming your Comments table has a field PostID, which designates the Post to which a Comment belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Even without enforceable foreign keys, the method to do the deletion is still the same.  Assuming you have a column like `post_id` in your Comments table

```
DELETE FROM Comments
 WHERE post_id = [Whatever Id];

DELETE FROM Posts
 WHERE PostID = [Whatever Id];
```

What you *really* lose with MyISAM is the ability to execute these two queries within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but you could set up a trigger to do cascading deletes (if you are using >=5.0)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Posts_AD AFTER DELETE ON Posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Comments WHERE post_id = OLD.PostID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```