# Trigger delete on relative tables without actually deleting a row

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm sorry if the question has already been asked before, but I could not find any references.
For instance, I have three tables: Device, DeviceInfo, and Slot (it's just an example) where both DeviceInfo and Slot have an foreign key to Device.

• DeviceInfo(device_id) has CASCADE delete when Device is removed

• Slot(device_id) has SET NULL when Device is removed

So, my main question, is it actually possible to trigger delete on relative tables without deleting a Device itself? So that row of some device will remain in the table, but relative table rows are either deleted or set to null.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes those are easy to achieve because the `Slot` is not in an FK and in a different table, and cuz `DeviceInfo` gets zapped with the cascade. Which just leaves the `Slot` for concern in the delete trigger of `Device`. Obviously use `InnoDB`

Comment: What should trigger the delete on the child tables?

Comment: Shadow, For example, when I delete Device, all the related DeviceInfos are deleted as well, and related Slots(device_id) are nullified. I need exactly this case, but without Device itself being deleted.

Comment: What about if you just write methods that check for external tables and them sets rows to null?

Comment: Edvin, yes, that one is possible solution. However I am wondering whether there is functionality, that I was searching for.
For instance, if it was like a transaction that holds only one table, So that I can delete the row (it would dissapear from the other tables, or show error in case of RESTRICT), then just rollback. Therefore I don't have to write methods, which will look for relational tables, set to null to destroy the connected rows, and if I were to add more foreign keys in the future.. so just automate

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a method that allows that. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126225/deleting-related-records-in-mysql) of how can you do as a closest solution. :)